# What's the suitable dependencies for cardview and recyclerview in appcompat 28.0.0-alpha3

Tags: android

I'm creating a project which using cardview and recycle view. There's no problem in my program when i build them, but when i run the project, this appear :

> Exception in thread "queued-resource-processor_31" java.lang.RuntimeException: >Timed out while waiting for slave aapt process make sure the aapt execute at C:\Users\Windows 8\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\build-tools\27.0.3\aapt2.exe can run successfully (some anti-virus may block it) or try setting environment variable SLAVE_AAPT_TIMEOUT to a value bigger than 5 seconds

and the project won't stop running unless i stop it. can you tell me what's wrong with my project?

In case you are wondering, this is my dependencies :

```
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0-alpha3'
implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:28.0.0-alpha3'
implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:28.0.0-alpha3'
```

Comment: The error tells you what might've happened. And a possible way to fix it. Did you try it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think this question is related to your dependencies. Have you tried disabling the antivirus/firewall or setting up slave environment variable as stated in error?

> try setting environment variable SLAVE_AAPT_TIMEOUT to a value bigger
>   than 5 seconds

If you dont know how to add environment variable, this may help.

Assuming that you are using Windows Environment as stated from your path,

1)Open Control panel

2)Go to System (In Recent variants, this may be under System and Security)

3)Find Advanced System settings

4)Select Environment Variables.

Here you will be able to add new environment variables or edit existing ones

5)Select System Variable

6)Find existing variable of this name. If found, edit it to 30.

If not, create a new variable by clicking New button .

> In Variable Name :- SLAVE_AAPT_TIMEOUT
>
> In Variable Value : 30